# Linking sections in sphinx output to the RST source

Tags: python-sphinx

Is there a method or plugin for sphinx documentation pages or sections to have a link back to the source - not a link to application source code but the actual sphinx RST files.

For example, a link saying "Contribute to this section" that links to the RST source file on github.

If this exists I'm not sure what to call it to find it, all I see are options to link to source code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is the configuration value [`html_show_sourcelink`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_show_sourcelink), and is supported by most themes:

> `html_show_sourcelink`
>   If `true` (and [`html_copy_source`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_copy_source) is `true` as well), links to the reST sources will be added to the sidebar. The default is `True`.

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to link to the github repo. With this feature it knows the filename and possibly line number, but linking to a copied source file doesn't really meet our goals.

Comment: That option has led me to a few random scripts that may work though, for example https://gist.github.com/mgedmin/6052926

Comment: We implemented an [Edit me on GitHub](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/) link for Pyramid docs by extending the basic theme. See https://github.com/Pylons/pylons-sphinx-themes/blob/master/pylons_sphinx_themes/pylons/layout.html#L28-L30

Comment: That could work, where do you define `github_user` and such? I tried putting them in conf.py but that wasn't the right spot it seems. Edit: Nevermind, this RTD page helped https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vcs.html